# I am confused with my SQL join since it's returning results different from my expectation

Tags: sql

I am trying to join two columns from a table to a single column in other table i.e. joining `eng_id` and `exam_id` from `table1` with `user_id` in `table2`.

```
select * 
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.eng_id = t2.user_id
  and t1.exam_id = t2.user_id;
```

This query is only returning records where `eng_id` and `exam_id` in table1 are similar (both ids are 18 or 20), if any record where these two ids are different, I don't see that record. Eng_id and Exam_id in table1 =(equals) to the user_id in table2

Although, the table is filled with records where `eng_id` and `exam_id` are different.

Would you please explain why this happens? This is my result:

[image]

Comment: I am doubting that exam_id is a true foreign key to user_id. Can you post the full table structures? edit: Also, you have too many tags. MySQL <> SQL Server.

Comment: if t1.eng_id=t2.user_id And t1.exam_id=t2.user_id then t1.eng_id = t1.exam_id by transitivity

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: First principles:  To answer a basic question like this, we need to know the table structure for the two tables you're joining.  And then tell us what you're trying to find out in the join.  And you should probably explain why you think t2.user_id is the same as t1.exam_id and t1.eng_id  (since that's what your original query means).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

```
IF t1.eng_id = t2.user_id AND t1.exam_id = t2.user_id THEN t1.eng_id = t1.exam_id;
```

With this SQL you will get all records that t1.eng_id are equals t1.exam_id.
Maybe you want to get records that t1.eng_id or t1.exam_id are equals t2.user_id. To this result, use this SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2
WHERE t1.eng_id = t2.user_id
OR t1.exam_id = t2.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s not clear by the details you provided, but it looks like you should do 2 joins between the first table (is it an exam table?) and the second table (an user table), somehing like:

```
select * 
from 
   table1 t1, 
   table2 t2,
   table2 t2_b
where t1.eng_id = t2.user_id
   And t1.exam_id = t2_b.user_id;
```

And, prefer to use more meaningfull alias, like "u_engineer" or "u_examiner"

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because in the where clause you are asking for t1.eng_id = t2.user_id
  and t1.exam_id = t2.user_id, notice you have an AND operation, it means, only when both conditions are met, which literally means, when eng_id and exam_id will be same in table t1.
Instead use like this:

```
select * 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.eng_id = t2.user_id
left join table2 t21 on t1.exam_id = t21.user_id;
```